# zsh prompt isn't showing the arrow key due to font issues

Tags: zsh, fonts, terminal-emulator, oh-my-zsh

I am having oh-my-zsh installed but the prompt is not showing the proper arrow which I Was expecting . I setup the arch linux from very scratch but I think I am missing those fonts. I am not sure which one is it . Can someone help me how to get this

[image]

What I am getting currently is this -

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue of not showing the expected icon is because
You do not have the required fonts ( in this case the `'->'`)

install powerline fonts with your package manager. (debian)

PS: After installation it is required to reset the font cache so that
it can then be reflected in your system.

```
sudo apt-get install powerline
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

else you can also pull the latest code from powerline from [this](https://github.com/powerline/fonts.git) and install manually.

```
# clone
git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts.git --depth=1
# install
cd fonts
./install.sh
# clean-up a bit
cd ..
rm -rf fonts
```

Comment: There is a thing which needs to be mentioned . I installed the powerline fonts . But it didnt help . But I took the second approach it worked . The reason was it reset the font cache . 

So for furture reference if someone is coming to this answer please note even if you install powerline fonts from package manager you need to reset the font cache

Comment: You don't even need powerline for an arrow. In zsh `echo '\u279c'` works without. You seem to be using the arrow from the Dingbats substitutes which is perhaps rendered slightly fatter. \u2192 is the normal arrow in Unicode.

Comment: yes, if all is needed just the arrow symbol then why go for installing a package (which also includes ever more).
Instead replacing the unicode that @okapi suggested would do the work.